# In laravel npm run dev errors:

Tags: laravel, npm

I have next errors output running npm command for my laravel 5.6 with bootstrap project:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test
> npm run development


> @ development /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

sh: 1: cross-env: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-04-25T10_54_37_776Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-04-25T10_54_37_794Z-debug.log
```

File /home/serge/.npm/_logs/2018-04-25T10_54_37_776Z-debug.log has:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'development' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.0
3 info using node@v9.11.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelopment', 'development', 'postdevelopment' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predevelopment: @
6 info lifecycle @~development: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~development: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~development: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test/node_modules/.bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/serge/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin
9 verbose lifecycle @~development: CWD: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test
10 silly lifecycle @~development: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
11 info lifecycle @~development: Failed to exec development script
12 verbose stack Error: @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
13 verbose pkgid @
14 verbose cwd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/B4test
15 verbose Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
16 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
17 verbose node v9.11.1
18 verbose npm  v6.0.0
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the @ development script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

In composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "components/highlightjs": "^9.12",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laracasts/utilities": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^3.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^5.1",
        "wboyz/laravel-enum": "^0.2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.7",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "laravel/dusk": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

In package.json :

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
        "vue2-collapse": "^1.0.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "element-ui": "^2.3.6",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
        "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.3.5",
        "marked": "^0.3.19",
        "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",
        "v-toaster": "^1.0.3",
        "vee-validate": "^2.0.6",
        "vee-validate-laravel": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.1.3",
        "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.2.1",
        "vue-fullcalendar": "^1.0.9",
        "vue-js-popover": "^1.1.7",
        "vue-moment": "^3.2.0",
        "vue-mouse-menu": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-nl2br": "0.0.5",
        "vue-notify-me": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-popperjs": "^1.2.6",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-select": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-simple-calendar": "^2.2.0",
        "vue-timeago": "^3.4.4",
        "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.29"
    }
}
```

Can you give a hint what could raize an error and how to fix it ?

Some error in config files or what?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to install the `cross-env` npm package.

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

It's listed in your dev dependencies, make sure to run `npm install` first.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to upgrade node to version 14.

Check your node version using

```
node -v
```

And then, install a stable version from [NODESOURCE](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

Basically,

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After this,

```
npm install
```

Followed by the command as per your needs.
In my case:

```
npm run dev
```

In case you still face issues, try [NPM ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle)

Just listing other keywords of this error:

> npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
>
> laravel npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE laravel
>
> error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script
> ERR! code EACCES
>
> ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> ERR! code EMISSINGARG

Answer (score 2):

I didn't need install nothing, I only run:

```
npm install
```

after:

```
npm audit fix
```

at the end:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and then:

```
npm run dev
```

it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Even when i used the same latest version of npm as was using before, got the above
errors on executing npm run dev command. Details of part of the error is "npm ERR! @ development: mix laravel npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE laravel error code ELIFECYCLE mix not recognised as internal command npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script ERR! code EACCESerrors"

Solution that worked for me : I had unstalled npm which was installed globally and reinstalled the same globally and "npm run dev" worked perfectly. Thanks for highlighting that the problem is associated with npm or incompatible versions of npm.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm cache clean –force
2. npm install
3. npm run dev

I used these links. it is working now.
[NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)
[In laravel npm run dev errors:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020636/in-laravel-npm-run-dev-errors)
[JetStream CSS and JS not working and showing @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73180945/jetstream-css-and-js-not-working-and-showing-viteresources-css-app-css-re)