# JetStream CSS and JS not working and showing @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-jetstream

**I installed livewire ,laravel mix and jetstream on laravel 8. But the Jetsream's css and js is not working and shows a message in header that '*@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])*' **

[image: JetStream Output]

**App.blade.php**

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        @livewireStyles

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <x-jet-banner />

        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @livewire('navigation-menu')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>

        @stack('modals')

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Replace the Welcome.blade.php and guest.blade.php and test.blade.php with this code, It's work for me**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

          <!-- Styles -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
          @livewireStyles
      
          <!-- Scripts -->
          <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. However, it will be good to know why the @vite directive is not working as expected.

Answer (score 32):

go to (`app.blade.php`, `guest.blade.php`) and remove `@vite` like this

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']) => Remove this and add following 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: by the way why @vite is used ?

Comment: tnx worked for mine... i think this happens because of using newer versions of Jetstream with an older version of laravel

Answer (score 3):

`Removing @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` **and replacing it with**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

VITE build configurations comes with only Laravel 9 & above, if we pull breeze or Jetstream to lower version `[Below Laravel 9]`, it will cause this issue, because lower version got the configuration of Laravel mix. Breeze & Jetstream by default with VITE configuration despite the version of laravel.

You have to update your laravel version above 9, for that you have to update your local PHP version above 8

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 8 does not support vite. So this is why you see your directive as a string.

Besides, for me, I have to force the assets to load via HTTPS schema. In AppServiceProvider.php boot() according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819095/8369356.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, I solved it by switching to PHP 8. You have to delete your project and re-create it after switching.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and discovered the reason was because I didn't name the file correctly, I used app.php instead of app.blade.php. Fixing that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to config/app.php and:

```
 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
 // 'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', '/'),
 'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', '/'),
```

.env file may do not content ASSET_URL parameter. Just set ASSET_URL same to APP_URL

All 404 NOT FOUND errors can be tracked to an URL misconfiguration

Comment: Sorry, after, run php artisan config:clear to reload config settings

Answer (score 0):

if you are in development just run this cmd

```
npm run dev
```

if you are in production mode

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/assets/app.YOUR_FILE_NAME.css">
<script src="/build/assets/app.YOUR_FILE_NAME.js"></script>
```

these two js / CSS files will be renamed every time you run: npm run build

if you want to get the names dynamically I made a foreach for that you can put it in your app.blade.php between  tag

```
@production
    @php $path = public_path('build\assets'); @endphp

@if (file_exists($path))
    @foreach (scandir($path) as $file)
        @if (strpos($file, '.css'))
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/assets/' . $file) }}">
        @endif
        @if (strpos($file, '.js'))
            @push('scripts')
                <script src="{{ asset('build/assets/' . $file) }}"></script>
            @endpush()
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
@else
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
@endproduction
```

and finally, add this before the body like this:

```
@stack('scripts') </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

just paste two line inside ( app.blade.php, guest.blade.php ) instead of @vite like this :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    
    {{-- @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']) --}}
```

and paste this code inside this folder public/mix-manifest.json

```
"/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
"/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
```

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a caching problem fo:
Run the command:

```
sail restart
```