# @vite( 'resources/css/app.css' 'resources/js/app.js' ) is not working with laravel 9, vite 4.0.0

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, laravel-authentication, laravel-vite

In Laravel 9 app, I installed Laravel auth (with Jetstreem livewire & vite-4.0.0) using the following commands:

`composer require laravel/jetstream`

`php artisan jetstream:install livewire`

`php artisan migrate`
`npm install`
`npm run dev`
`npm run build`

In my ***app.blade.php*** and ***guest.blade.php*** @vite( 'resources/css/app.css' 'resources/js/app.js' ) is not working. CSS & JS is not loading.

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])

        <!-- Styles -->
        @livewireStyles
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
    @livewireScripts
    </body>

</html>
```

I have tried the solutions of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73180945/jetstream-css-and-js-not-working-and-showing-viteresources-css-app-css-re) but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **app.css**. Vite config works great without CSS.

Here's the solution:

1. **vite.config.js**

---

Remove `'resources/js/app.css'` from **vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

2. Add CSS to **resources/js/app.js**

---

```
`import '../css/app.css';`
```

Like

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.plugin(focus);

Alpine.start();
```

3. Using **@vite** in views

Because our CSS is already imported into our **app.js**, we will only use

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

in our layout view files: **app.blade.php** and **guest.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</head>

<body>
    <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

4. Build your app

---

`npm run build`

Note:

Use `php optimize:clear` for cache cleaning, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added them too into vite.config.js with corresponding path

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(
{
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/admin/scss/style.scss',
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: Yes ```import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
    'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```