# Installing create-react-app gives npm ERR! shasum check failed and npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

**Errors when i use sudo npm install create-react-app -g**
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-39-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "create-react-app" "-g"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-16477-77596b49/registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 8e4d2a256c0e2185c6b18ad694aec968b83cb1d1
npm ERR! Actual:   5eb06eb521673d0940a4deb11baf89d62647f193
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-2.2.1.tgz

**when use npm install create-react-app**
- npm-version : 6.0.0
- node-version: 8.11.1
*error is:*
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dilipcoder/.npm/_logs/2018-05-05T11_34_14_721Z-debug.log

**i have already tried these options**

- npm cache clean --force
- reinstalling npm and node
- switching different version of npm

[error which I get while installing create-react-app other packages installed properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohJzR.png)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the error *npm ERR! shasum check failed* and *npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near'....'* ,   will be solved by switching npm reigistry from the list of given npm registry.

List of Npm registry:

- https://registry.npmjs.org/ (Dfault One)
- http://r.cnpmjs.org/
- https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
- https://registry.nodejitsu.com/
- http://registry.mirror.cqupt.edu.cn
- https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry
- https://npm.open-registry.dev/ (https://open-registry.dev)

To switch just type

`npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"`

Replace the registry url with the above urls check which one works for you.

After That:

`npm cache clear --force`

`npm cache verify`

now error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

"npm cache clean --force" didn't work for me but removing package-lock.json worked.
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990#issuecomment-395750082

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Removing package-lock.json worked for me.

Add Powershell script or Linux script as below,

**Powershell:**

```
Remove-Item package-lock.json  -Force
```

**Linux:**

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

**Path In Azure Devops:**

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\appName\appName\ClientApp\node_modules'
```

Note - appName is an example you can add a path as per your source code.