# NPM install fails with mysterious "Unexpected token in JSON" error

Tags: json, npm

The double space in the subject between "token" and "in" is intentional (edit: SO has stripped the double space!). Opening the NPM log file in nano gives a bit more of a clue;

```
3911 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^@ in JSON at position 1764 while parsing near '...rsion":"0.2.3","depe^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...'
3911 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
3911 verbose stack     at parseJson (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
3911 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
3911 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
3911 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
3912 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/uat-deployments/app
3913 verbose Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
3914 verbose argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/npm" "install"
3915 verbose node v8.15.0
3916 verbose npm  v6.7.0
3917 error Unexpected token ^@ in JSON at position 1764 while parsing near '...rsion":"0.2.3","depe^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...'
3918 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

There is no `package-lock.json` (though I think `npm install` should / would generate one). I have done `rm -r node_modules` and `npm cache clean --force`.

`npm install` works fine on my Mac, just not on the build server (Ubuntu). All was working fine previously and `package.json` has not changed recently. I wonder if a third party dependency's `package-lock.json` is causing trouble, problem is I have no idea where to look.

Any help appreciated. I'm not an expert in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same problem 
what ended up working for us was changing the NPM registry

[Installing create-react-app gives npm ERR! shasum check failed and npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189096/installing-create-react-app-gives-npm-err-shasum-check-failed-and-npm-err-unex/50191315#50191315)

Comment: I didn't follow up on this for a few days, and when I did ... it just worked. So was probably a problem on their side, so I bet your solution would have worked,