# npm install fails for ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, angular7, npm-install

Hi when i tried to install **ionic-angular** am getting this error

```
PS D:\ENDART\DART-MOBILE> npm install ionic-angular
npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 423538 while parsing near '...gZvBqA=="
npm ERR!     }
npm ERR!   }
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! '

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NIKITHRA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-11T05_18_26_257Z-debug.log
PS D:\ENDART\DART-MOBILE>
```

I tried this solution. But didnt solve.
[Installing create-react-app gives npm ERR! shasum check failed and npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189096/installing-create-react-app-gives-npm-err-shasum-check-failed-and-npm-err-unex/50191315#50191315)

```
PS D:\ENDART\DART-MOBILE> npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
PS D:\ENDART\DART-MOBILE> npm cache clear --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
PS D:\ENDART\DART-MOBILE> npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.036s
```

How to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure the [HTTP_PROXY](http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.com/2013/11/set-and-reset-proxy-for-git-and-npm.html) in your environment:

```
http://username:password@proxy.server.com:port
```

---

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Then try this:

```
rm -f package-lock.json
```

and then

```
npm install
```