# Unable to create a react app using "create-react-app"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have installed "create-react-app" globally on my pc using "npm install create-react-app -g". And it worked just fine for months. I had previously created a lot of react app using the "create-react-app app-name" command. And it worked flawlessly. Until a few days ago when it sudden stopped working and started giving errors. I have tried various things suggested but with no luck. So after days of trying to solve the issue I am asking this question.

I have tried doing the following things:

```
1> using the "npm cache clean --force" and then "npm cache verify".
2> I also unabled my antivirus (norton) and then ran the commands.
3> I installed the latest node version
4> I intalled the latest npm version and updated it using the command "npm install npm@latest -g"
5> I followed the instructions on this stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189096/installing-create-react-app-gives-npm-err-shasum-check-failed-and-npm-err-unex/50191315#50191315 to change the registry.
And a few other things. But nothing has worked.
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
D:\codes\react\maximilianUdemy\project1>create-react-app react-mytest-app

Creating a new React app in D:\codes\react\maximilianUdemy\project1\react-mytest-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...HqQqP7Ky/f49Ar0oPZ\n4'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-20T10_24_27_969Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-mytest-app/ from D:\codes\react\maximilianUdemy\project1
Done.
```

Below is an excerpt from the `C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-20T10_24_27_969Z-debug.log`. Since the log is really big (664 lines), I have only noted from when the error started showing.

```
471 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...HqQqP7Ky/f49Ar0oPZ\n4'
471 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
471 verbose stack     at parseJson (D:\Program_Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
471 verbose stack     at D:\Program_Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
471 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
472 verbose cwd D:\codes\react\maximilianUdemy\project1\react-mytest-app
473 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
474 verbose argv "D:\\Program_Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program_Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
475 verbose node v12.6.0
476 verbose npm  v6.9.0
477 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...HqQqP7Ky/f49Ar0oPZ\n4'
478 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Try this `npx create-react-app react-mytest-app`

Comment: try uninstall and reinstall using npm uninstall -g create-react-app

Comment: @ravibagul91 I tried that too. It also gives the same error

Comment: @Sushilzzz I had previously updated npm but it didn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled as you said, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: try deleting everything under `C:\Users\<yourUser>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`

Comment: Oh and If you have yarn installed you need to set the flag: `create-react-app my-project --use-npm` otherwise it will cache it in yarn and you would need to clear yarn's cache

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Comment: I too faced the same issue. npm create-react-app suddenly not working and I used 
 npx create-react-app it worked fine. I can't understand why npm create-react-app not working

Comment: Can you try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `npx create-react-app my-app`

I think also information in [this link](https://link.medium.com/1POngNGp63) will help you.

Comment: what's the problem statement? What have you tried already? What error messages appeared when trying to run said command?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is create-react-app version with respect to node version.

Create new project

> **npx create-react-app project_name --template all**

[Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node)

[create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-all)

Answer (score 0):

First use `npx create-react-app`, but if the problem persists ->

This will happen usually due to 1 of the two reasons :

1. Your npm registry is messed up somehow.
2. You have an old version of 'create-react-app'.

To solve this try:

1. Run `npm get registry` to see your current, and `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` to set the registry to default.
2. To get the new version of create-react-app, simply uninstall the old one globally through `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and  then run `npx create-react-app` for creating your react app.