# Unabe to install firebase-tools via npm in cli Kali

Tags: reactjs, firebase

After typing in terminal this

```
sudo install -g firebase-tools
```

I get the following error

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/exegesis reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-19T04_41_56_097Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in exactly the same situation.
After switching the registry (as below) and trying a few times,
I was able to install firebase-tools.

npm config set registry "http://r.cnpmjs.org/"

[Installing create-react-app gives npm ERR! shasum check failed and npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mojOzGIEI2rg0m24Yb5Oq'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189096/installing-create-react-app-gives-npm-err-shasum-check-failed-and-npm-err-unex?rq=1)

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellow https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/below Don't blindly trust your spellchecker.