# Error when use 'vue create my-project': Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

the command:

```
vue create vue-hello
```

the Error:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...kwrap":false,"publish'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/hope111/.npm/_logs/2018-05-27T03_02_46_740Z-debug.log
>    ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org --disturl=https://npm.taobao.org/dist

Here is the picture of the error:

[image: picture of the error]

I had used the  `npm cache clean --force`, but it did not work

Comment: it's likely from the libraries, have you tried to update your vue-cli and retry the whole thing?

Comment: i install the vue-cli today, it is 3.0.0-beta.11, it is the latest version

Comment: That's a duplicate, check my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249619/7668448

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm update`
3. `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: OP already has the latest version and has also cleared the cache already.

Comment: Please explain why this would solve the question at hand ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1366#issuecomment-392321634), it seems that updating to `npm 6+` solves some `vue-cli3.0.0-beta.11` bugs

Comment: I have updated my npm to 6.1.0  and vue-cli to 3.0.0-beta.11 but did not work, I have changed the vuejs-templates, now I am using this one :
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: I have updated my npm to 6.1.0  and vue-cli to 3.0.0-beta.11 but did not work, I have changed the vuejs-templates, now I am using this one :
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Comment: You were not choosing any templates from vue-cli right? When you run `vue create my-project` the first thing I a am presented with is _"select a preset"_ and both _"Manually select features_" and _"default (bable, eslint)"_ work just fine. Sorry if I can't help further, last thing could be that some plugins cannot be downloaded on your connection as said [here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990), that's why I would try the most basic configuration.

Comment: I  chose the default preset when I  run vue create my-project , but it show the above error, maybe it is my environment problem.  In a word, thank you for answering my question! If I find a solution, I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe running these commands will solve it. It helped me with a similar problem when trying to create a new project with `vue create`

error:
~/.vuerc may be outdated. Please delete it and re-run vue-cli in manual mode.

solution:

`$ npm uninstall -g vue`

`$ npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

`$ npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

`$ npm cache clean --force`

`$ npm install -g vue`

`$ npm install -g @vue/cli`