# Angular Cli Error Installing: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: angular

When installing `angular cli` .I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ´...,"helper-reflinks":
```

[image]

Can anyone guide me what to do? I will really appreciate your support

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157638/error-installing-angular-cli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing Angular Cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157638/error-installing-angular-cli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 2):

try uninstalling and re-installing angular cli again, 
`npm remove @angular/cli` 
`npm i @angular/cli@latest -g`

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me

> npm cache clean --force

then run

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Taken from [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your cache by tapings using:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then install the latest cli using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```