# unexpected end of json input react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am just beginning my coding journey and I am just starting out with react but when I try creating a new app, I get the following error. It says unexpected end of JSON input.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gin-precompile- 
charco'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07- 
24T07_21_16_208Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting robofriends / from C:\Users\vaibh\Desktop
Done.
```

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` try

Comment: Look at this question and its first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Comment: Please check the answer and mark as resolved if it solves your query.

Answer (score 5):

It is due to the npm cache.

You can solve it by:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also, make sure your npm is updated to the latest.

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

And try again!!

Comment: thanks, but didn't work for me :(