# npm error - Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Anytime i run `create-react-native-app 'Project-Name'`. I get this  error on my node package manager

```
Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
```

How can i fix this? I tried this over 10 times, cleared my cache and also updated my npm version
Is there something i must install or do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Just once clear the cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then try

```
npm i create-react-native-app
```

again, see if this works, coz it worked for me!