# Error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ge-2.2.1.tgz"},"engin'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Exception:

> verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing
>   near '...ge-2.2.1.tgz"},"engin' 169 verbose stack     at JSON.parse
>   () 169 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
>   169 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
>   169 verbose stack     at  169 verbose stack     at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

---

Looking for help and support.
Thanks

Comment: Try npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: @DharmarajKavatagi :no luck..:(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If not working :

Delete **package.lock.json** file and try again

Comment: After following the above steps, got error:npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...://registry.npmjs.org'

Comment: delete package.lock.json file and try again

Answer (score 1):

I started facing this issue after upgrading `npm` package.

You can resolve this with: `npm cache clean --force`

voila, reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

Curious how that error happen, look at my answer here, that explain that well  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249619/7668448

You will quickly understand. I put some nice images to illustrate the thing. Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else ends up here and the above answers don't work for them I found after hours of fiddling that downgrading my npm from version 5 to version 4 did the trick:

```
npm install -g npm@4
```

After which I closed my CMD and opened it again and was able to install the Angular CLI with the normal command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Hope this helps someone along the way, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am using :

- node v12.17.0
- npm 6.14.4
- Windows 10

I was trying to install Amplify 4.21.0 when I faced:

> Error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ....

It worked for me after doing the following steps:

- Uninstall and reinstall node.
- Delete the files in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
- Using the command line as administrator, I run npm cache clean --force
- I deleted the package.lock.json file in C:\Users\username.
- Then installed Amplify using npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

after you've finished running the code above
then try installing angular again
`npm install -g @angular/cli`