# I faced problem when I want to install angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I already have node installed.

[image]

Everything is ok, but I don't know why I cannot install angular/cli

My commands:
C:\myApp>node -v
v8.11.3

C:\myApp>npm -v
5.6.0

C:\myApp>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....1","minimatch":"^3.0'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HamedPC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-08T13_23_51_111Z-debug.log

I tried `npm cache clean --force`, but still did not work.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the log file? The lines of errors, at least.

Comment: looks like that version of the cli has a bug in it, you can specify what version to install

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, won't `npm install -g @angular/cli` install the latest version?

Comment: yeah it will, but as i stated, that version looks to have a bug in it, so specifying the version (eg `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4`) will install the cli, might be a slight bit outdated but it would atleast install the cli

Comment: Did you try updating npm?

Comment: Try installing using `yarn` with the command `yarn global add @angular/cli`.
To install `yarn`, use `npm i -g yarn`.

Comment: @inthevortex theres no point in installing yarn when npm works perfectly fine

Comment: @mast3rd3mon that's true too.

Comment: yes, I tried by updating the version of node to the latest, but it is not solved.

Answer (score -1):

The latest CLI build is 7.0.4. There might be issues with the package. I have 7.0.3 installed globally on my system which has no such issues. Try installing using the command `npm i -g @angular/cli@7.0.3`.

If the problem persists further, submit an issue properly to their [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues).

Comment: with running npm i -g @angular/cli@7.0.3:npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ebug":"^2.1.3","denod'

Comment: Check out the first and second answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack). Also try running the command as `sudo`, if in linux or as `admin` if on windows.