# Encounter error when installing react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error whenever I NPM install react-router-dom in vs code:

[image]

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...stack-launcher":"^1.0'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-18T09_03_43_417Z-debug.log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Comment: can you put your package.json ? seems that there is a typo error

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you missed a comma after `'...stack-launcher":"^1.0'` in the package.json file.

If not delete the `node_modules` folder, delete `package-lock.json` file, run `npm cache clean --force` and try to re-install.