# Issue while installing Angular Cli

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install

```
C:\Users\Tauseef\Desktop>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...lr8Pw+hghLU8LySls45dS'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tauseef\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T18_54_50_700Z-debug.log
```

> That are happening while i am installing an Angular Cli....

Comment: reinstall node js after clearing cache and angular cli,that might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing npm cache. Should work fine

`npm cache clean --force`