# Facing error while installing firebase via npm | Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install firebase in my fresh react project, I could not able to install it.

Whether it is an error or the npm is taking time. I am waiting for more than half an hour.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this (you may need to run `sudo` or if you're on Windows, open `cmd` as Admin)..

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm install firebase
```

Comment: This worked perfectly a year later. Reading up on this, npm cache is self healing, so would be nice to know *why* this is the solution! :D

Comment: It looks like this happens when NPM cache becomes corrupt. It doesn't happen just for firebase. I honestly can't seem to find a clear answer on why. May be worth opening another question - it may serve as a good resource down the line (as there doesn't appear to be anything clear online right now).

Answer (score 2):

while the above answer seems to work for most cases it wasn't true for my case.
I tried

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install firebase
```

no luck!

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47675478/13011799) which explained a lot about npm caches which also concluded the above method should work and maybe to just verify cache before installing firebase

```
   npm cache clean -f
   npm install firebase
   npm verify cache
```

still, no luck so I just decided to add it in package.json as a dependency with the latest stable version of firebase (8.0.0) at this time.

so go to package.json file and in the dependencies section

```
"dependencies": {
     "firebase": "^8.0.0",
     ...other dependencies
     }
```

and do

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm@latest
```

this should work for similar cases check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47675478/13011799) to see how caching on npm works in detail.

Comment: Nice find! Thank you for the explanation as well.