# How to fix "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing" on Vue CLI installation

Tags: vue.js, npm, installation

I want to install Vue CLI . and i run this on my Git Bash .

```
ECLIPSE@DESKTOP-AIUUOKR MINGW64 ~
$ npm install -g @vue/cli
```

but having error like this :

```
ECLIPSE@DESKTOP-AIUUOKR MINGW64 ~
$ npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ery":"latest","throug'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ECLIPSE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-09T02_48_52_427Z-debug.log
```

i try with solution in stackoverflow in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

. i try with

```
ECLIPSE@DESKTOP-AIUUOKR MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

but i try to install again , its have same error . someone can help me about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem and simple `npm cache clean --force` command did not help too.
I solved the problem by deleting C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm and C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache directories and running an `npm cache clean --force` command after this. Then, `npm install` worked properly.
If the problem continues to appear, reinstall Node.js and NPM. Do not forget to check if all previous files connected with them are deleted before the installation!

Answer (score 0):

This process work for me

1 - Run your Command Invite/Terminal as Administrator

2 - Install the Vue CLI globally with the command :

```
npm install -g vue-cli
```