# "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" during Npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I encountered error during  building Jenkins

**Jenkins Log**

> > Task :api:processResources
> > Task :api:classes
> > Task :web:nodeSetup
> > Task :web:npmSetup /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web/.gradle/npm/npm-v6.11.2/bin/npm
> > -> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web/.gradle/npm/npm-v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
> > /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web/.gradle/npm/npm-v6.11.2/bin/npx
> > -> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web/.gradle/npm/npm-v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
>
> - npm@6.11.2 added 430 packages from 832 contributors in 6.837s
>
> > Task :web:npmInstall FAILED npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-10-16T01_11_20_594Z-debug.log
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':web:npmInstall'.
>
> > Process 'command '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web/.gradle/npm/npm-v6.11.2/bin/npm''
> > finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 33s

**/var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-10-16T01_11_20_594Z-debug.log**

```
17 silly saveTree   │ ├─┬ clean-css@4.2.1
17 silly saveTree   │ │ └── source-map@0.6.1
17 silly saveTree   │ ├── commander@2.17.1
17 silly saveTree   │ └── he@1.2.0
17 silly saveTree   └─┬ loader-utils@0.2.17
17 silly saveTree     ├── big.js@3.2.0
17 silly saveTree     ├── emojis-list@2.1.0
17 silly saveTree     └── json5@0.5.1
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
18 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:99:22)
18 verbose stack     at BB.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12)
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
18 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
18 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
18 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
19 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hds_v2_docker/web
20 verbose Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
21 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
22 verbose node v8.16.0
23 verbose npm  v6.9.0
24 error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try removing your `package-lock.json` to see if that helps.

```
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

Edit: If the issue still persists, delete `node_modules` as well.

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I've already tried but I got same error

Comment: Try removing node_modules as well. rm -rf node_modules after cd-ing into your app directory.

Comment: Use `del package-lock.json` command on Windows OS. Also close editors and delete `node_modules`. Both are must.

Comment: This is just a temporary solution. I believe it would be great to provide a solution that permanently fixes the issue based on the inputs provided by author of the question

Comment: In my case npm-shrinkwrap.json had to be removed to resolve the issue

Comment: Passing `-rf` flags to `rm` shouldn't be the default.
`rm package-lock.json`
`rm -r node_modules` 
should in the most cases suffice.

Comment: Although this doesn't provide an explanation of *why* deleting package-lock.json works, it did seem to get me past that speed bump.

Answer (score 43):

You have to remove **both** `package-lock.json` **and** `node_modules/`.

If you don't remove both, the problem will come back on the next `npm install`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The question is why this happens?

Comment: package-lock.json only was already enough for me =)

Comment: This worked for me, the error message was similar (`Cannot read property 'extraneous' of undefined`).

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error when running `npm install` in my repo. I don't use Jenkins, but I found a generic approach to debugging (and ultimately resolving) this issue in NPM.

1. Open the npm debug log file that the cli provides you. (on Windows, under `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs` by default)
2. Look for the stack trace of the error, at the bottom of the file.
3. The first three lines of the error stack trace should be something like:

```
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.5.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
18 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.5.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:113:22)
```

4. Open up the `inflate-shrinkwrap.js` file, and go to the line listed in stack-trace line #3 above.
5. Add this debugging code: (just before the line [in stack-trace] which calls `tarballToVersion`)

```
if (sw.version == null) {
    console.error(`
        NPM is trying to retrieve package "${name}" with version "undefined"!
        Package location: ${(onDiskChild || {}).location}
        Package parse error:`, (onDiskChild || {}).error);
}
```

6. Run `npm install` (or whatever command yields the error). You should see an output like this:

```
        NPM is trying to retrieve package with version "undefined"!
        Package location: /firebase-feedback/webpack-dev-middleware
        Package parse error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Root\Apps\@V\@Modules\firebase-feedback\Main\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\package.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Root\\Apps\\@V\\@Modules\\firebase-feedback\\Main\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-middleware\\package.json'
}
```

7. Go to the path specified in the internal error. You should find that the package.json file at that path is indeed missing.
8. Resolve that underlying "package.json" issue as you see fit. (for me, this was by deleting the `C:/Root/Apps/@V/@Modules/firebase-feedback/Main/node_modules` folder, then running `npm install` in the `Main` folder)

---

Note that in my case, the underlying issue (of the missing package.json file) appears to have been caused by me accidentally running `npm install` from the parent project (which uses my `firebase-feedback` library), while I had that library "npm linked".

I normally use [npm-safe-install](https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install) to avoid these sorts of issues (when using `npm link`), but I must have forgotten sometime recently -- leading to NPM mangling the npm-linked libraries' `node_modules` folders.

Similar issues relating to `npm link` have happened before, but I hoped NPM would have patched these sorts of issues by now. Apparently not; though version 7 of NPM has [been stated](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17287#issuecomment-400833982) as going to have a rewrite in that area, so hopefully that will solve it long term.

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove project Package-lock.json file. then try to install what you want.

[image: You can find that file in main project directory]

Comment: No, it should not. This is "the recommended workaround" but is incredibly broken in practice. Having a locked dependency in package.json in no way ensures that dependency's dependencies will remain consistent, so removing the package-lock.json file, npm installing, and generating a newlock file *will allow those sub-dependencies to change, which often completely breaks any future building. Using an existing lock file is often the only way to maintain builds (that is the POINT of the file, after all) so removing it completely goes against the reason for its existence.

Comment: @DanielM It should be safe if you have package-lock.json checked into version control as you should

Answer (score 4):

The error may vary on what npm internals file it can be thrown! (And i wonder for all the possible reasons)! And it should be a bug!

(in my last case: it was on `[_canPlaceDep]` method of the file `build-ideal-tree.js` of npm!

### Note

If none of the common methods works! And that you are using **nodejs v15+** and one of **latest npm version**! Go to the last part! The problem that i call the nodejs **VERSIONS HELL**! (NOTE: after reflection! For npm it may not be a version HELL! READ TO KNOW)

## How to try to solve

### Removing node_modules

```sh
\rm -r node_modules
```

Reinstall after

```sh
npm install
```

(NOTICE: that may still not work)

You can try to remove package.lock too!

### Clearing the cache

```sh
npm cache clean --force
```

That can work if the cache get currupted somehow! But the common error is more of `Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ...`

You can check my answer here (that explain it well): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249619/7668448

### Removing package.lock (which is not adviced)

```sh
rm package.lock
```

#### Why not advised

From @DanielIM comment

> No, it should not. This is "the recommended workaround" but is incredibly broken in practice. Having a locked dependency in package.json in no way ensures that dependency's dependencies will remain consistent, so removing the package-lock.json file, npm installing, and generating a newlock file *will allow those sub-dependencies to change, which often completely breaks any future building. Using an existing lock file is often the only way to maintain builds (that is the POINT of the file, after all) so removing it completely goes against the reason for its existence.

So generally it's nice to **leave that as a last resort**! If it does not work ! You can try with **removing node_modules** too!

## Reinstalling nodejs or NPM

A problem can happen at npm level! Trying to reinstall can be a nice way!

To test quickly in place of reinstalling! Using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) (nodejs version manager) and switching to another version is fast and interesting! Because we can also test for **VERSION HELL PROBLEM**!

If it works after switch! Then either it's a problem with npm and a reinstallation may fix it! Or it's a **version Hell problem** (a bug)!

How to reinstall fast! Again use nvm!

```sh
nvm uninstall v15
```

then

```sh
nvm install v15
```

then use it

```sh
nvm use v15
```

You can just install another version and use it! (v14 for example)

Check the VERSION HELL PROBLEM And how to use nvm to switch between versions!

## The uncommon or new! THE VERSIONS HELL

In this year! I encountered many nodejs **VERSIONS HELL problems**! (I like to call them that) (because i gave them a name! The skies are blessing me with more) (irony)

To list them quickly:

- **Node v14 HELL (POSTGRES)** and causing problem for **pg** module (postgres) [because of breaking changes! That pg was depending on!] (if you are using **knex** or any orm or query builder! And use it with postgres! Big chance you'll encounter it! If you just upgrade nodejs version alone! [Solution: upgrade pg versoin to the latest (>=8.0.3) [They made a fix] (Can check a full detailed explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64639717/7668448)]
- **Typescript v4 HELL**! A similar problem! Where typescript in one of my project fail internally with `cannot read property "" of undefined`! Rolling back to **v3.9** run successfully! No problem!

### Fix Our problem (`Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined`)

If you are using **node v15**! Try with **node v14** (npm v6.14.8)! That may be it! An npm bug! That's a first thought can be! That what i thought at first!

**That's was the case for me!** In this last problem! I tried all the solutions that i'm familiar with! And they were already listed here too! None worked! And more when i removed **node_modules**! I was `Please not another version HELL`! And **yea** it was exactly that! It worked well with `**node v14** (npm v6.14.8)`. Which suggest a [BUG].

**Then reflecting a bit on it! It was like hey! When i change the version! I'm using another nodejs installation! Which can just not have the problem. A problem with npm structure or something and a re-installation may fix it (as mentioned above)!**

After it ! I tried with `node v15.3.0`. And it worked all ok! After the installation was all right done! I went back to node v15.0.1! And it worked again! So the problem is **absolutely not a VERSION HELL problem**

I'm still uncapable to explain what did happen! But in short! Using **NVM**! To try with another version! Is a good way to go about it! You can reinstall quickly the current version too!

### Big Take down (for the VERSION HELL)

Starting from nodejs v14! And v15! Or just generally! It's nice to be skeptical about the versions! More of a reason when it doesn't make sense! And that's about all the problems not just npm! There is so many **VERSIONS HELL** problems! I encountred 2 up to now! Being alerted to the **VERSIONS HELL** can save you a lot of time!

### How to test fast and also switch nodejs version quickly

To be fast at testing this and checking! Mostly for any internal error that will come! I'll **google it quickly**! And **try another version of nodejs** or **whatever in question (ex: typescript)**! I can too debug (console.log) The internal file where the error was thrown! And try to figure out something!

But that's it! It's **really interesting to check for other versions**! (nodejs, typescript, ... [remember be skeptical or alerted])

For nodejs To do it quickly:

#### NVM to switch quickly nodejs versions (npm)

Use **[NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)** (nvm is a version manager for node.js,)

Quick installation of version in NVM

```
nvm install v14
```

Quick switch to another node version

```
nvm use v14
```

(Check the doc for the details! And installation process)

#### For switching and testing some npm module version (ex: typescript)

If it's a cli tool! you can install a precise version globaly

```sh
npm i -g typescript@3.9
```

use the `@` syntax!

Once you verify and test you can switch back to whatever you like!

If it's in a project! You can do the same (not globally)! use the `@` syntax to precise the version!

```
npm i moduleName@<versionSpecifier>
```

or with saving

```
npm i moduleName@<versionSpecifier> --save
```

Version specifier use **SEMVER** convention (https://semver.org/).

#### Last tip (use npx in your scripts)

It's nice to set a version internal to the project! For example

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.6",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7", // <===== Typescript version 3.9 (for this project)
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
```

In scripts i use npx:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc && gulp build",
```

When we use npx this way with a nodjes module cli tool! npx will check first if the module is available in the local node_modules! If found will use it (use global otherwise, or Download latest and run)!

So doing what i'm suggesting! Will make sure your project will run independently from whatever you have in global!

(Read more about npx if you don't know the tool well)

Answer (score 0):

Following steps work for me -

1. Delete npm and npm catch folder from ../AppData/Roaming
2. Install latest node js for [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
3. Retry all the steps according to your repo.