# @material-ui/core match of undefined

Tags: material-ui

Having an issue installing the latest version of @material-ui/core something to do with

> Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Also windows 10 here.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\russe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose npm-session f730c2d6854e1504
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall adstichr@0.1.0
7 info lifecycle adstichr@0.1.0~preinstall: adstichr@0.1.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2063ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 19ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2159ms
17 silly saveTree adstichr@0.1.0
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
18 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:99:22)
18 verbose stack     at BB.each (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12)
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:611:10)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:142:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
18 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\russe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
18 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
18 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
19 verbose cwd C:\Users\russe\Documents\adstichr
20 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19018
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\russe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
22 verbose node v10.16.3
23 verbose npm  v6.13.0
24 error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's probably an [npm issue](https://npm.community/t/cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined/203). 
Try to delete your package-lock.json and node_modules, and install after that:

```
$ rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
$ npm install
```

Comment: My issue was the same when trying to install **@material-ui/lab** as `npm install @material-ui/lab` but this answer solved the error. Thanks!

Comment: For reference purposes (for others reading), there is a generic way to debug these `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369937/2441655