# npm install issues TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm having massive issues installing the packages via npm. I'm getting nothing but this log as an output and have no idea where or how to fix this issue.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v13.5.0
4 verbose npm-session ae2d5c224ea0a56c
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall Zupa.Apps.Market.Web
7 info lifecycle @~preinstall: @
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 2661ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 31ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2791ms
17 silly saveTree Zupa.Apps.Market.Web
17 silly saveTree +-- @aspnet/signalr@1.1.4
17 silly saveTree | `-- ws@6.2.1
17 silly saveTree +-- @babel/core@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/code-frame@7.5.5
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/highlight@7.5.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/generator@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/types@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/helpers@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | +-- @babel/template@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | | `-- @babel/parser@7.7.3
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/traverse@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | |   +-- @babel/helper-function-name@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   | `-- @babel/helper-get-function-arity@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   +-- @babel/helper-split-export-declaration@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   `-- debug@4.1.1
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/parser@7.7.3
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/template@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/traverse@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/types@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | `-- debug@4.1.1
17 silly saveTree +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.6.2
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/helper-plugin-utils@7.0.0
17 silly saveTree | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree +-- @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.6.2
17 silly saveTree | `-- @babel/helper-module-imports@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree +-- @babel/preset-env@7.7.1
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | +-- @babel/helper-remap-async-to-generator@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | | +-- @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | | `-- @babel/helper-wrap-function@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin@7.7.2
17 silly saveTree | |   `-- @babel/helper-regex@7.5.5
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-syntax-async-generators@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-syntax-json-strings@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.6.3
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | +-- @babel/helper-define-map@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | +-- @babel/helper-optimise-call-expression@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-replace-supers@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   `-- @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.6.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-dotall-regex@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys@7.5.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   `-- @babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.4.4
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd@7.5.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-module-transforms@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | |   `-- @babel/helper-simple-access@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-hoist-variables@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-new-target@7.4.4
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.5.5
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.4.4
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/helper-call-delegate@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-reserved-words@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.6.2
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.4.4
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | `-- @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree +-- @babel/preset-react@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | | `-- @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0
17 silly saveTree | +-- @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.5.0
17 silly saveTree | `-- @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree |   `-- @babel/helper-builder-react-jsx@7.7.0
17 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.25
17 silly saveTree | `-- @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@0.2.25
17 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons@5.11.2
17 silly saveTree +-- @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.11.2
17 silly saveTree `-- @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.7
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
18 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:99:22)
18 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:619:10)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:699:18)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
18 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
18 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:445:21)
19 verbose cwd C:\Zupa_Source_Code\Zupa.Apps.Market\src\Zupa.Apps.Market.Web
20 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
22 verbose node v13.5.0
23 verbose npm  v6.13.4
24 error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

So far I've deleted the node_modules folder and the package-lock file and it's still not installing properly. What's odd looking at the log is that it looks like its failing based on a dependency of another dependency? I'm not even sure what dependency that's coming from to try and downgrade it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This looks like something went wrong between node and something in the global cache folder when I whipped that it allowed me to npm I again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a generic way to debug these `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` errors here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369937/2441655