# NPM build issue with webpack-dev-server

Tags: npm-install, webpack-dev-server

I'm hoping someone can advise on a problem with NPM building that resulted from trying to use an old version of webpack-dev-server.  I'm following a React tutorial and using the old versions of utilities it suggests. I installed webpack-dev-server version 2.5.1 and NPM couldn't build anymore.  In my IDE I used Yarn to move up to webpack-dev-server 2.11.5 and now my application is running fine.  "npm run dev-server" and "npm run build" work fine now.  However, when I try "npm install" I get "ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined".

I'm assuming if I can't run npm install I could get into trouble later on. Can someone help me understand what is wrong?  My log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose npm-session bf54bf8ec307523c
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall indecision-appnew@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle indecision-appnew@1.0.0~preinstall: indecision-appnew@1.0.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 787ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 6ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-cli 271ms (from cache)
16 silly pacote version manifest for babel-cli@6.24.1 fetched in 279ms
17 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
18 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1106ms
19 silly saveTree indecision-appnew@1.0.0
19 silly saveTree └─┬ babel-cli@6.24.1
19 silly saveTree   ├── babel-core@6.25.0
19 silly saveTree   └─┬ chokidar@1.7.0
19 silly saveTree     ├─┬ anymatch@1.3.2
19 silly saveTree     │ └─┬ micromatch@2.3.11
19 silly saveTree     │   ├─┬ arr-diff@2.0.0
19 silly saveTree     │   │ └── arr-flatten@1.1.0
19 silly saveTree     │   ├── array-unique@0.2.1
19 silly saveTree     │   ├── braces@1.8.5
19 silly saveTree     │   ├── expand-brackets@0.1.5
19 silly saveTree     │   └── extglob@0.3.2
19 silly saveTree     └── async-each@1.0.3
20 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
20 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
20 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:99:22)
20 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12
20 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
20 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
20 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
20 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
20 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
20 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
20 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
20 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
20 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
20 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
20 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
20 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
20 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
21 verbose cwd /Library/WebServer/Documents/reactCourse/indecision-appNew
22 verbose Darwin 19.4.0
23 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
24 verbose node v12.16.2
25 verbose npm  v6.14.4
26 error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "indecision-appnew",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "some student",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a generic way to debug these `TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` errors here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369937/2441655