# "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" during npm install, but fixing it only works once

Tags: node.js, npm

The solution to the problem is to delete `node_modules` and `package_lock.json`. This is great, and it fixes the issue - but only once. I have to do this **every single time** that I want to install another package. Every time I fix it, the issue returns on the next `npm install`.

This is my debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.1
4 verbose npm-session 32e87fe4b8fbb7a5
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall client@0.1.0
7 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~preinstall: client@0.1.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 1517ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 18ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1603ms
17 silly saveTree client@0.1.0
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
18 verbose stack     at inflatableChild (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:113:22)
18 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:55:12
18 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotValue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:155:18)
18 verbose stack     at Object.gotAccum (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\reduce.js:144:25)
18 verbose stack     at Object.tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:517:31)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:18)
18 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:611:10)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:142:12)
18 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
18 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
18 verbose stack     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
19 verbose cwd C:\NodeApps\react-twitch-logs\client
20 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
21 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
22 verbose node v12.18.1
23 verbose npm  v6.14.5
24 error Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I need a permanent solution to this. The issue came around when I tried installing webpack, but it was a newer version than what `react-scripts` was using. And now it's screwed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was some kind of conflict with `react-scripts`.

Running `npm run eject`, and then removing `package_lock.json` and `node_modules` fixes it completely.

Comment: For reference purposes (for others), there is a generic way to debug these `Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64369937/2441655