# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined

Tags: npm, npm-install

**My Setup/versions:**
Windows:  10 N 64Bit

NPM: 7.0.7

Node: v15.0.1

**Problem:**
I want to *npm install* my project, however I receive the following error:
`npm ERR! Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined`
Below is a screenshot of the full error:

**What I have tried so far:**
Reinstalling `NodeJS` by removing it completely (uninstalling via windows) and removing `npm/node` folders in `programfiles/appdata`.

Deleting `Node_module` + `package_lock.json`.



**Sources:**

From looking around I found that deleting node_module + package_lock.json should have already fixed my issue. Sadly this is not the case for me.

[Link 1](https://npm.community/t/cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined/203/2), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404547/cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined-during-npm-install), [Link 3](https://dev.to/sewvandiii/npm-err-cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined-3hb5)

If you guys require the `.log` file I can edit this post and add it as well. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with npm 7.0.3, then I switched to the LTS version 6.14.8 and `npm install` just went fine.