# Google App Engine - Node.js Infinity Loading

Tags: html, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have set nodejs app (standard app - like free tier) and deployed it via cloud shell, but when I go to the https://[ID].du.r.appspot.com/ , it loades infinitely.

app.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static('public', {
    extensions: ['html', 'htm'],
  }));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}.`);
});
```

app.yaml:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16
```

package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "example-expressjs",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "<div align=\"center\">   <a href=\"https://koyeb.com\">     <img src=\"https://www.koyeb.com/static/images/icons/koyeb.svg\" alt=\"Logo\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\">   </a>   <h3 align=\"center\">Koyeb Serverless Platform</h3>   <p align=\"center\">     Deploy a _FIXME_APP_TYPE_ application on Koyeb     <br />     <a href=\"https://koyeb.com\">Learn more about Koyeb</a>     ·     <a href=\"https://koyeb.com/docs\">Explore the documentation</a>     ·     <a href=\"https://koyeb.com/tutorials\">Discover our tutorials</a>   </p> </div>",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
    }
}
```

package-lock.json:

```json
{
    "name": "example-expressjs",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "lockfileVersion": 3,
    "requires": true,
    "packages": {
        "": {
            "name": "example-expressjs",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "dependencies": {
                "express": "^4.18.2"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/accepts": {
            "version": "1.3.8",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/-/accepts-1.3.8.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-PYAthTa2m2VKxuvSD3DPC/Gy+U+sOA1LAuT8mkmRuvw+NACSaeXEQ+NHcVF7rONl6qcaxV3Uuemwawk+7+SJLw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "mime-types": "~2.1.34",
                "negotiator": "0.6.3"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/array-flatten": {
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/array-flatten/-/array-flatten-1.1.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-ml9pkFGx5wczKPKgCJaLZOopVdI="
        },
        "node_modules/body-parser": {
            "version": "1.20.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser/-/body-parser-1.20.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-jWi7abTbYwajOytWCQc37VulmWiRae5RyTpaCyDcS5/lMdtwSz5lOpDE67srw/HYe35f1z3fDQw+3txg7gNtWw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "bytes": "3.1.2",
                "content-type": "~1.0.4",
                "debug": "2.6.9",
                "depd": "2.0.0",
                "destroy": "1.2.0",
                "http-errors": "2.0.0",
                "iconv-lite": "0.4.24",
                "on-finished": "2.4.1",
                "qs": "6.11.0",
                "raw-body": "2.5.1",
                "type-is": "~1.6.18",
                "unpipe": "1.0.0"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8",
                "npm": "1.2.8000 || >= 1.4.16"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/bytes": {
            "version": "3.1.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/-/bytes-3.1.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-/Nf7TyzTx6S3yRJObOAV7956r8cr2+Oj8AC5dt8wSP3BQAoeX58NoHyCU8P8zGkNXStjTSi6fzO6F0pBdcYbEg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/call-bind": {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/call-bind/-/call-bind-1.0.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-7O+FbCihrB5WGbFYesctwmTKae6rOiIzmz1icreWJ+0aA7LJfuqhEso2T9ncpcFtzMQtzXf2QGGueWJGTYsqrA==",
            "dependencies": {
                "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
                "get-intrinsic": "^1.0.2"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/content-disposition": {
            "version": "0.5.4",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/content-disposition/-/content-disposition-0.5.4.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-FveZTNuGw04cxlAiWbzi6zTAL/lhehaWbTtgluJh4/E95DqMwTmha3KZN1aAWA8cFIhHzMZUvLevkw5Rqk+tSQ==",
            "dependencies": {
                "safe-buffer": "5.2.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/content-type": {
            "version": "1.0.5",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/content-type/-/content-type-1.0.5.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-nTjqfcBFEipKdXCv4YDQWCfmcLZKm81ldF0pAopTvyrFGVbcR6P/VAAd5G7N+0tTr8QqiU0tFadD6FK4NtJwOA==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/cookie": {
            "version": "0.5.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/-/cookie-0.5.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-YZ3GUyn/o8gfKJlnlX7g7xq4gyO6OSuhGPKaaGssGB2qgDUS0gPgtTvoyZLTt9Ab6dC4hfc9dV5arkvc/OCmrw==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/cookie-signature": {
            "version": "1.0.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/-/cookie-signature-1.0.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-4wOogrNCzD7oylE6eZmXNNqzriw="
        },
        "node_modules/debug": {
            "version": "2.6.9",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-2.6.9.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-bC7ElrdJaJnPbAP+1EotYvqZsb3ecl5wi6Bfi6BJTUcNowp6cvspg0jXznRTKDjm/E7AdgFBVeAPVMNcKGsHMA==",
            "dependencies": {
                "ms": "2.0.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/depd": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/depd/-/depd-2.0.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-g7nH6P6dyDioJogAAGprGpCtVImJhpPk/roCzdb3fIh61/s/nPsfR6onyMwkCAR/OlC3yBC0lESvUoQEAssIrw==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/destroy": {
            "version": "1.2.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/destroy/-/destroy-1.2.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-2sJGJTaXIIaR1w4iJSNoN0hnMY7Gpc/n8D4qSCJw8QqFWXf7cuAgnEHxBpweaVcPevC2l3KpjYCx3NypQQgaJg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8",
                "npm": "1.2.8000 || >= 1.4.16"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/ee-first": {
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ee-first/-/ee-first-1.1.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-WMwm9LhRUo+WUaRN+vRuETqG89IgZphVSNkdFgeb6sS/E4OrDIN7t48CAewSHXc6C8lefD8KKfr5vY61brQlow=="
        },
        "node_modules/encodeurl": {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/encodeurl/-/encodeurl-1.0.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-TPJXq8JqFaVYm2CWmPvnP2Iyo4ZSM7/QKcSmuMLDObfpH5fi7RUGmd/rTDf+rut/saiDiQEeVTNgAmJEdAOx0w==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/escape-html": {
            "version": "1.0.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/-/escape-html-1.0.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-NiSupZ4OeuGwr68lGIeym/ksIZMJodUGOSCZ/FSnTxcrekbvqrgdUxlJOMpijaKZVjAJrWrGs/6Jy8OMuyj9ow=="
        },
        "node_modules/etag": {
            "version": "1.8.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/etag/-/etag-1.8.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-aIL5Fx7mawVa300al2BnEE4iNvo1qETxLrPI/o05L7z6go7fCw1J6EQmbK4FmJ2AS7kgVF/KEZWufBfdClMcPg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/express": {
            "version": "4.18.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-4.18.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-5/PsL6iGPdfQ/lKM1UuielYgv3BUoJfz1aUwU9vHZ+J7gyvwdQXFEBIEIaxeGf0GIcreATNyBExtalisDbuMqQ==",
            "dependencies": {
                "accepts": "~1.3.8",
                "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
                "body-parser": "1.20.1",
                "content-disposition": "0.5.4",
                "content-type": "~1.0.4",
                "cookie": "0.5.0",
                "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
                "debug": "2.6.9",
                "depd": "2.0.0",
                "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
                "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
                "etag": "~1.8.1",
                "finalhandler": "1.2.0",
                "fresh": "0.5.2",
                "http-errors": "2.0.0",
                "merge-descriptors": "1.0.1",
                "methods": "~1.1.2",
                "on-finished": "2.4.1",
                "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
                "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
                "proxy-addr": "~2.0.7",
                "qs": "6.11.0",
                "range-parser": "~1.2.1",
                "safe-buffer": "5.2.1",
                "send": "0.18.0",
                "serve-static": "1.15.0",
                "setprototypeof": "1.2.0",
                "statuses": "2.0.1",
                "type-is": "~1.6.18",
                "utils-merge": "1.0.1",
                "vary": "~1.1.2"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.10.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/finalhandler": {
            "version": "1.2.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/finalhandler/-/finalhandler-1.2.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-5uXcUVftlQMFnWC9qu/svkWv3GTd2PfUhK/3PLkYNAe7FbqJMt3515HaxE6eRL74GdsriiwujiawdaB1BpEISg==",
            "dependencies": {
                "debug": "2.6.9",
                "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
                "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
                "on-finished": "2.4.1",
                "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
                "statuses": "2.0.1",
                "unpipe": "~1.0.0"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/forwarded": {
            "version": "0.2.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/forwarded/-/forwarded-0.2.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-buRG0fpBtRHSTCOASe6hD258tEubFoRLb4ZNA6NxMVHNw2gOcwHo9wyablzMzOA5z9xA9L1KNjk/Nt6MT9aYow==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/fresh": {
            "version": "0.5.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.5.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-zJ2mQYM18rEFOudeV4GShTGIQ7RbzA7ozbU9I/XBpm7kqgMywgmylMwXHxZJmkVoYkna9d2pVXVXPdYTP9ej8Q==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/function-bind": {
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/function-bind/-/function-bind-1.1.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-yIovAzMX49sF8Yl58fSCWJ5svSLuaibPxXQJFLmBObTuCr0Mf1KiPopGM9NiFjiYBCbfaa2Fh6breQ6ANVTI0A=="
        },
        "node_modules/get-intrinsic": {
            "version": "1.2.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/get-intrinsic/-/get-intrinsic-1.2.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-2DcsyfABl+gVHEfCOaTrWgyt+tb6MSEGmKq+kI5HwLbIYgjgmMcV8KQ41uaKz1xxUcn9tJtgFbQUEVcEbd0FYw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
                "has": "^1.0.3",
                "has-proto": "^1.0.1",
                "has-symbols": "^1.0.3"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/has": {
            "version": "1.0.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/has/-/has-1.0.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-f2dvO0VU6Oej7RkWJGrehjbzMAjFp5/VKPp5tTpWIV4JHHZK1/BxbFRtf/siA2SWTe09caDmVtYYzWEIbBS4zw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "function-bind": "^1.1.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.4.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/has-proto": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/has-proto/-/has-proto-1.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-7qE+iP+O+bgF9clE5+UoBFzE65mlBiVj3tKCrlNQ0Ogwm0BjpT/gK4SlLYDMybDh5I3TCTKnPPa0oMG7JDYrhg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.4"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/has-symbols": {
            "version": "1.0.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/has-symbols/-/has-symbols-1.0.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-l3LCuF6MgDNwTDKkdYGEihYjt5pRPbEg46rtlmnSPlUbgmB8LOIrKJbYYFBSbnPaJexMKtiPO8hmeRjRz2Td+A==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.4"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/http-errors": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/http-errors/-/http-errors-2.0.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-FtwrG/euBzaEjYeRqOgly7G0qviiXoJWnvEH2Z1plBdXgbyjv34pHTSb9zoeHMyDy33+DWy5Wt9Wo+TURtOYSQ==",
            "dependencies": {
                "depd": "2.0.0",
                "inherits": "2.0.4",
                "setprototypeof": "1.2.0",
                "statuses": "2.0.1",
                "toidentifier": "1.0.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/iconv-lite": {
            "version": "0.4.24",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.24.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-v3MXnZAcvnywkTUEZomIActle7RXXeedOR31wwl7VlyoXO4Qi9arvSenNQWne1TcRwhCL1HwLI21bEqdpj8/rA==",
            "dependencies": {
                "safer-buffer": ">= 2.1.2 < 3"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">=0.10.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/inherits": {
            "version": "2.0.4",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.4.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-k/vGaX4/Yla3WzyMCvTQOXYeIHvqOKtnqBduzTHpzpQZzAskKMhZ2K+EnBiSM9zGSoIFeMpXKxa4dYeZIQqewQ=="
        },
        "node_modules/ipaddr.js": {
            "version": "1.9.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ipaddr.js/-/ipaddr.js-1.9.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-0KI/607xoxSToH7GjN1FfSbLoU0+btTicjsQSWQlh/hZykN8KpmMf7uYwPW3R+akZ6R/w18ZlXSHBYXiYUPO3g==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.10"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/media-typer": {
            "version": "0.3.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/media-typer/-/media-typer-0.3.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-dq+qelQ9akHpcOl/gUVRTxVIOkAJ1wR3QAvb4RsVjS8oVoFjDGTc679wJYmUmknUF5HwMLOgb5O+a3KxfWapPQ==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/merge-descriptors": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/-/merge-descriptors-1.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-sAqqVW3YtEVoFQ7J0blT8/kMu2E="
        },
        "node_modules/methods": {
            "version": "1.1.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-1.1.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-VSmk1nZUE07cxSZmVoNbD4Ua/O4=",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/mime": {
            "version": "1.6.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.6.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-x0Vn8spI+wuJ1O6S7gnbaQg8Pxh4NNHb7KSINmEWKiPE4RKOplvijn+NkmYmmRgP68mc70j2EbeTFRsrswaQeg==",
            "bin": {
                "mime": "cli.js"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">=4"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/mime-db": {
            "version": "1.52.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db/-/mime-db-1.52.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-sPU4uV7dYlvtWJxwwxHD0PuihVNiE7TyAbQ5SWxDCB9mUYvOgroQOwYQQOKPJ8CIbE+1ETVlOoK1UC2nU3gYvg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/mime-types": {
            "version": "2.1.35",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.35.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-ZDY+bPm5zTTF+YpCrAU9nK0UgICYPT0QtT1NZWFv4s++TNkcgVaT0g6+4R2uI4MjQjzysHB1zxuWL50hzaeXiw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "mime-db": "1.52.0"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/ms": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.0.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-Tpp60P6IUJDTuOq/5Z8cdskzJujfwqfOTkrwIwj7IRISpnkJnT6SyJ4PCPnGMoFjC9ddhal5KVIYtAt97ix05A=="
        },
        "node_modules/negotiator": {
            "version": "0.6.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator/-/negotiator-0.6.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-+EUsqGPLsM+j/zdChZjsnX51g4XrHFOIXwfnCVPGlQk/k5giakcKsuxCObBRu6DSm9opw/O6slWbJdghQM4bBg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/object-inspect": {
            "version": "1.12.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/object-inspect/-/object-inspect-1.12.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-geUvdk7c+eizMNUDkRpW1wJwgfOiOeHbxBR/hLXK1aT6zmVSO0jsQcs7fj6MGw89jC/cjGfLcNOrtMYtGqm81g==",
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/on-finished": {
            "version": "2.4.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/on-finished/-/on-finished-2.4.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-oVlzkg3ENAhCk2zdv7IJwd/QUD4z2RxRwpkcGY8psCVcCYZNq4wYnVWALHM+brtuJjePWiYF/ClmuDr8Ch5+kg==",
            "dependencies": {
                "ee-first": "1.1.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/parseurl": {
            "version": "1.3.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl/-/parseurl-1.3.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-CiyeOxFT/JZyN5m0z9PfXw4SCBJ6Sygz1Dpl0wqjlhDEGGBP1GnsUVEL0p63hoG1fcj3fHynXi9NYO4nWOL+qQ==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/path-to-regexp": {
            "version": "0.1.7",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/-/path-to-regexp-0.1.7.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-32BBeABfUi8V60SQ5yR6G/qmf4w="
        },
        "node_modules/proxy-addr": {
            "version": "2.0.7",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/proxy-addr/-/proxy-addr-2.0.7.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-llQsMLSUDUPT44jdrU/O37qlnifitDP+ZwrmmZcoSKyLKvtZxpyV0n2/bD/N4tBAAZ/gJEdZU7KMraoK1+XYAg==",
            "dependencies": {
                "forwarded": "0.2.0",
                "ipaddr.js": "1.9.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.10"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/qs": {
            "version": "6.11.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-6.11.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-MvjoMCJwEarSbUYk5O+nmoSzSutSsTwF85zcHPQ9OrlFoZOYIjaqBAJIqIXjptyD5vThxGq52Xu/MaJzRkIk4Q==",
            "dependencies": {
                "side-channel": "^1.0.4"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">=0.6"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/range-parser": {
            "version": "1.2.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-1.2.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-Hrgsx+orqoygnmhFbKaHE6c296J+HTAQXoxEF6gNupROmmGJRoyzfG3ccAveqCBrwr/2yxQ5BVd/GTl5agOwSg==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/raw-body": {
            "version": "2.5.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-body/-/raw-body-2.5.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-qqJBtEyVgS0ZmPGdCFPWJ3FreoqvG4MVQln/kCgF7Olq95IbOp0/BWyMwbdtn4VTvkM8Y7khCQ2Xgk/tcrCXig==",
            "dependencies": {
                "bytes": "3.1.2",
                "http-errors": "2.0.0",
                "iconv-lite": "0.4.24",
                "unpipe": "1.0.0"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/safe-buffer": {
            "version": "5.2.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safe-buffer/-/safe-buffer-5.2.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-rp3So07KcdmmKbGvgaNxQSJr7bGVSVk5S9Eq1F+ppbRo70+YeaDxkw5Dd8NPN+GD6bjnYm2VuPuCXmpuYvmCXQ==",
            "funding": [
                {
                    "type": "github",
                    "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/feross"
                },
                {
                    "type": "patreon",
                    "url": "https://www.patreon.com/feross"
                },
                {
                    "type": "consulting",
                    "url": "https://feross.org/support"
                }
            ]
        },
        "node_modules/safer-buffer": {
            "version": "2.1.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer/-/safer-buffer-2.1.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-YZo3K82SD7Riyi0E1EQPojLz7kpepnSQI9IyPbHHg1XXXevb5dJI7tpyN2ADxGcQbHG7vcyRHk0cbwqcQriUtg=="
        },
        "node_modules/send": {
            "version": "0.18.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.18.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-qqWzuOjSFOuqPjFe4NOsMLafToQQwBSOEpS+FwEt3A2V3vKubTquT3vmLTQpFgMXp8AlFWFuP1qKaJZOtPpVXg==",
            "dependencies": {
                "debug": "2.6.9",
                "depd": "2.0.0",
                "destroy": "1.2.0",
                "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
                "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
                "etag": "~1.8.1",
                "fresh": "0.5.2",
                "http-errors": "2.0.0",
                "mime": "1.6.0",
                "ms": "2.1.3",
                "on-finished": "2.4.1",
                "range-parser": "~1.2.1",
                "statuses": "2.0.1"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/send/node_modules/ms": {
            "version": "2.1.3",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.1.3.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-6FlzubTLZG3J2a/NVCAleEhjzq5oxgHyaCU9yYXvcLsvoVaHJq/s5xXI6/XXP6tz7R9xAOtHnSO/tXtF3WRTlA=="
        },
        "node_modules/serve-static": {
            "version": "1.15.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static/-/serve-static-1.15.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-XGuRDNjXUijsUL0vl6nSD7cwURuzEgglbOaFuZM9g3kwDXOWVTck0jLzjPzGD+TazWbboZYu52/9/XPdUgne9g==",
            "dependencies": {
                "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
                "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
                "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
                "send": "0.18.0"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/setprototypeof": {
            "version": "1.2.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/setprototypeof/-/setprototypeof-1.2.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-E5LDX7Wrp85Kil5bhZv46j8jOeboKq5JMmYM3gVGdGH8xFpPWXUMsNrlODCrkoxMEeNi/XZIwuRvY4XNwYMJpw=="
        },
        "node_modules/side-channel": {
            "version": "1.0.4",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/side-channel/-/side-channel-1.0.4.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-q5XPytqFEIKHkGdiMIrY10mvLRvnQh42/+GoBlFW3b2LXLE2xxJpZFdm94we0BaoV3RwJyGqg5wS7epxTv0Zvw==",
            "dependencies": {
                "call-bind": "^1.0.0",
                "get-intrinsic": "^1.0.2",
                "object-inspect": "^1.9.0"
            },
            "funding": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/statuses": {
            "version": "2.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses/-/statuses-2.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-RwNA9Z/7PrK06rYLIzFMlaF+l73iwpzsqRIFgbMLbTcLD6cOao82TaWefPXQvB2fOC4AjuYSEndS7N/mTCbkdQ==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/toidentifier": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/toidentifier/-/toidentifier-1.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-o5sSPKEkg/DIQNmH43V0/uerLrpzVedkUh8tGNvaeXpfpuwjKenlSox/2O/BTlZUtEe+JG7s5YhEz608PlAHRA==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">=0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/type-is": {
            "version": "1.6.18",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is/-/type-is-1.6.18.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-TkRKr9sUTxEH8MdfuCSP7VizJyzRNMjj2J2do2Jr3Kym598JVdEksuzPQCnlFPW4ky9Q+iA+ma9BGm06XQBy8g==",
            "dependencies": {
                "media-typer": "0.3.0",
                "mime-types": "~2.1.24"
            },
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.6"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/unpipe": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/unpipe/-/unpipe-1.0.0.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-pjy2bYhSsufwWlKwPc+l3cN7+wuJlK6uz0YdJEOlQDbl6jo/YlPi4mb8agUkVC8BF7V8NuzeyPNqRksA3hztKQ==",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/utils-merge": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/-/utils-merge-1.0.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-n5VxD1CiZ5R7LMwSR0HBAoQn5xM=",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.4.0"
            }
        },
        "node_modules/vary": {
            "version": "1.1.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vary/-/vary-1.1.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-IpnwLG3tMNSllhsLn3RSShj2NPw=",
            "engines": {
                "node": ">= 0.8"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute `npm start` on cloud shell, it opens web server properly.

I also checked if it is browser problem, opened it with secret mode, but still can't accessible.

I have also stop and restart service on cloud console.

Current server.js:
[image]

package.json:
[image]

sorry for image code, since i’m on ipad now.. :(

This is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: Check the logs. What does it say?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Thanks for replying.
https://www.playbook.com/s/cyan/d8xM2DckzRZ9K6PCosAX5LpZ?assetToken=rPKjPcLiw2ToouzUrH5qf9L2 is the log file, FYI.
GET

500

602.218 s

Chrome 116.0.0.0
/

[pid1] started [session:5BQ0F4L]

[serve] Args: {runtimeLanguage:nodejs runtimeName:nodejs16 memoryMB:384 positional:[]}

[serve] Running /bin/sh -c exec node app.js

Server running at http://localhost:8000.

It logs these repeatedly, in short.

Comment: Update:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404547/cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined-during-npm-install I've deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, and add "module.exports = app;" at the bottom of app.js, app.yaml to runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
but still experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup)

> By default, the runtime starts your application by running `node server.js`. If you specify a start script in your package.json file, the runtime runs the specified start script instead.

Your post says your file is named `app.js` but your package.json has `index.js`.

Based on the assumption that your file is named `app.js`, you can do **one** of the following

1. Rename `app.js` to `server.js`
2. Add the following to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

**Separately**, I see that you have html in your description in package.json. I don't know that it will do anything (you should double-check that it has an effect). This [documentation](https://heynode.com/tutorial/what-packagejson/) gives the impression that it should just be a string but that isn't part of the issue you're currently facing.

**Update**

In `server.js`,

change `const port = 8000;`

to `const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;`

I was able to reproduce your issue. When the port was set to 8000, the page never loaded (what you call infinite loading). When I modified the code (as stated above), it worked. Note that the code above is what you have in our template which is from Google Cloud Samples. Don't have the time now to figure out why it can't work with a specified port number from a user (it'll probably be somewhere in the documentation)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I’ve renamed it to server.js, remove the script on package.json before, but still the same issue persists.

Comment: + I have added current code to the article.

Comment: Don't post code images when you ask a question. Remove ```"main": "server.js"``` from ```package.json```. If your App is still not starting, check your logs (it should something more meaningful now that it has a script to run ( I assume ```server.js``` is in your root and not some sub-directory)

Comment: Since you're using ```index.html```, add the structure of your project folder to your question. It could be that your code isn't able to locate that file

Comment: Hi, I have added structure. Furthermore, I’ve used your tool (nocommandline), just in case, but the same issue still persists.

Comment: Our tool has nothing to do with this. Your logs should have more information now and should make it easier to debug but will take a look at the information you've added later on today

Comment: Hi, I also removed main : server.js , and in the log, it only displays starting message (server is running at localhost:8000), but still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255072/discussion-between-nocommandline-and-cyan).

Comment: Thank you! changing port to environmental variable worked for me!