# Getting errors when installing angular cli

Tags: angular-cli

I am getting the following error when i run 'npm install -g @angular/cli":

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"broccoli-uglify-js"'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean npm cache,

> npm cache clean --f

Then run install again,

> npm i -g @angular/cli