# npm failed with return code 1 azure pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are developing react.js application. I just push the updated src files to github. After that it will work with azure pipeline. last commit we just comment the 4 lines then code pushed to github but now its returns **npm failed with return code 1 azure pipeline** we don't have a access permission for Azure. SO how can I fix this issue

node : v18.2.0npm : 8.9.0"react": "^17.0.1",:

```
Node.js v18.14.1 ##[warning]Couldn't find a debug log in the cache or working directory ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1 ##[section]Finishing: npm build
```

Comment: without the logs, it would be really difficult to debug. Does it build successfully in your local?

Comment: also, does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865815/how-to-resolve-azure-pipeline-error-npm-failed-with-return-code-1-npm-install

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah, Application working fine in local i can able to run and make a build in local but while I commit the code to github it returns same error