# Why do I keep receiving an error when trying to install my react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

This is my first time trying out React and it's very demoralising to keep seeing the same error over and over again. I tried all three of these codes seperately
`npx create-react-app myapp`
`npm init react-app myapp`
`npm install -g create-react-app` then `create-react-app myapp`

All which gave me:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0"},'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{hiddenForPrivacyReasons}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-18T14_12_44_513Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\{hiddenForPrivacyReasons}\codes\app
Done.
```

Help!!!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `react-app` and other scripts

Simply:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Refer: document of [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)