# Error when starting a new ionic project Json

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed ionic, ionic error starting a new project.I tried to reinstall.

```
 npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing '...:"@ionic/angular-tool'

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

 npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alperen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04- 
 24T09_09_36_306Z-debug.log

 [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

 npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: please provide the log from log file and npm error for unexpected end of JSON input means there's a problem with that specific json file and must be resolved

Comment: Have you [checked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)
run npm install -g @angular/cli