# How to install react app without an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

Hello guys i am trying to install react into my system but from 2 days i am facing the error for several times now. At first, i have used these commands to install react app and it was working fine for me

```
1. npm install -g creat-react-app
2. create-react-app reactapp
```

but form 2 days i was facing error while choosing these options to install, therefore I visited https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ where it was clearly stated- If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version. Then i used the command `npx create-react-app reactapp` but i am facing this error. I have multiple time uninstalled nodejs and installed, also have used the command `npm cache clean --force`too. But not working!!!!

```
e:\react-learn>npm uninstall -g create-react-app
removed 98 packages in 5.031s

e:\react-learn>npx create-react-app reactapp
npx: installed 98 in 39.888s

Creating a new React app in e:\react-learn\reactapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...wRDiDz3X/FqXhQ==","
sh'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-23T12_48_46_9
79Z-debug.log
```

How to resolve this error???And one interesting thing you know when i copied my previous project and run `npm start` it is working fine. What is the issue reactapp is justing eating my nerves...

Comment: Delete package-lock.json and run npm install again please.

Comment: From where i need to delete package-lock.json???

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the issue , the project is not yet created for you .

Comment: yes!! i have only package.json file

Comment: 1. delete npm and npm-cache folders in <path of error file> then execute cmd 
2. npm cache clear --force , npm cache verify

Comment: okay deleted now in cmd  i will just run this code ``` npx create-react-app reactapp```

Comment: Yes then!!! i have followed your steps

Comment: Any luck this time? Here I could see some solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Comment: Nothing is happening scripts are stuck only written installing

Comment: Nothing is happening same problem!!!

Comment: I would recommend to raise an issue on github.

Comment: Okay!!! Thanks for your recommendation i will surely do that

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache and try again.
You can run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

or

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Comment: Next what to do

Comment: Are you running npm or npx?

Comment: I am running npm

Comment: can you try uninstalling create-react-app, then clear your cache =>restart your computer=>install create-react-app and run create-react-app as an administrator with the

Comment: I had a similar issue sometimes ago that is how I resolved the issue. Please the --force flag

Comment: 1. Run cmd as admin 2.  Uninstall create-react-app 3. clear cache use both commands with the --force flag 4. restart your PC. 5. install create-react-app 5. create-your project again.

Comment: Okay i have not tasted that please be here till i made the changes

Comment: install create-react-app wit this command ```npx create-react-app my-app```

Comment: No, I will prefer you run npm install create-react-app -g first

Comment: Okay did you mean `npm install -g create-react app` then ```npx create-react-app my-app``` like this

Comment: npm install -g create-react-app then create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 0):

Try using `npx create-react-app client --use-npm`. Sometimes some issues arise due to package managers .

Comment: used that one too but no solution

Comment: try using other methods of installing react ,refer https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ ,to install using Yarn

Comment: tried all just yarn is left i think i need to opt that now