# problem with install and creat my first react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[here is the img description of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPOTa.jpg)

first it creates the folder (my-app), but after a few seconds it will be removed automatically. Either I installed the latest version of node.js.

$ npx create-react-app my-app
npx : 98 installé(s) en 23.154s

Creating a new React app in D:\Mon-Travail-Personnel\my-work-with-REACT\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

until know it's good but after : 
**
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rg\r\n\r\nwsFcBAEBCAA'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\khith\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-29T16_51_36_753Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\Mon-Travail-Personnel\my-work-with-REACT
Done.
**

Comment: Check this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack). It probably tackles your problem

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this,

1. Clear cache: `npm cache clean --force`
2. Install create-react-app globally: `npm i create-react-app -g`
3. Create your React project: `create-react-app my-app`

The problem should mostly be resolved with Step 1.

Comment: with the answer one . it's not working . one person told me re install the Node js. i did thaaat . then  it works . thank you so much bro

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a different network, either a different Wi-Fi network or using a mobile hotspot. Then, try again to create the react app: npx create-react-app <project_name>.

Hope this should help you.This Works For me.

Is this okay with you?