# npm Error: installing faker.js and Axios have the same error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

** I am new to React.js **

{
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"7.4.3":{"name":"@ba'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hanifullah Jamalzai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-12T00_45_53_215Z-debug.log
}

```
{
  "name": "pics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably error in your package.json

Comment: How to solve it

Comment: It depends. You can edit your question to include your whole package.json

Comment: Question edited

Comment: It looks more like npm problem, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack

Comment: would you help me please, still have problems and this is new type of error

Comment: ```npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/istanbul-lib-source-maps (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hanifullah Jamalzai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-12T01_45_02_883Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215786/discussion-between-hanifullah-jamalzai-and-gieted).

Comment: That looks like a network issue, did you resolve this?

Comment: yarn  worked for me, still installing all packages with yarn