# npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1

Tags: node.js, npm

This is what happened when I tried to `npm install`.

```sh
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...5","@babel/types":"7.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-18T01_59_09_875Z-debug.log
```

I did `npm remove bootstrap popper.js` but it won't work. I'm using Windows 10. So what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Comment: The problem isn't with popper, something went wrong while downloading the babel package.  See the linked duplicate and try clearing your npm cache.