# Why am I unable to create a new react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I get the following error while using

npx create-react-app meme

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"bin":"./bin"},"di'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/saurav/.npm/_logs/2020-07-07T17_04_39_147Z-debug.log
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 1
```

This problem happened on its own, one minute it was working the next it didnt.

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack) also [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7261).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 0):

clearing npm cache can be a solution.

for clean npm cache :

1.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2. to update npm

```
npm i npm@latest -g
```

3. install npm by

```
npm install
```