# "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near" Error : npm install -g@angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Always give an error message when i try to install angular using this `npm install -g@angular/cli`

> PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\sonal> npm install -g @angular/cli npm ERR!
> Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...EGIN PGP
> SIGNATURE---'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-12T09_04_02_173Z-debug.log.

For this we use node version 12.18.0 and npm version 6.14.6.Please help me for solving this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896884/2358409

Answer (score 0):

**step 0**: run this command

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

`npm cache clean`

**step 1**: delete this folder: C:\Users%YOUR-USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm

**step 2**: uninstall Nodejs from Windows

**step 3**: restart your PC

**step 4**: install a fresh copy of Nodejs from here:[Link](https://nodejs.org/en/)

**step 5**: install the CLI globally

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Thank u for this solution@Jay Parmar.I tried but it not worked for me. I again find the same error.Please suggest any other solution for this problem@ Jay Parmar..