# vue create with e2e showing strange error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I tried creating project using vue create but I get following error all the time

```
✨  Creating project in C:\Users\....
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."^5.8.23","babel-tape'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HariC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-01T13_14_04_441Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

I have chosen everything in except typescript support and es-lint while creating the app.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error was due to corrupt cache. Referred to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896884/9640177

> npm cache clean --force