# I have been trying to install or create a react app but I kept getting this error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have been trying to install or create a react app but I kept getting this error message
" npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...5VmmIPyPaAPmy1Iv3blBY'"

Also:
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Madu Emmanuel IP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-13T11_40_59_715Z-debug.log

Comment: that's not enough context... what are you getting prior to the error? What is the full error message? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Command Prompt, `cd` into the desired folder and write:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```

Once done, write:

```
npx create-react-app <project-name>
```

It should work perfectly.

Comment: You don't need to install `create-react-app` globally for `npx` to work

Comment: You still should though. No need to include create-react-app in any dependency

Comment: @SagiRika AFAIK npx will search for the package in the local and global registry and if it's not found, it will download the package and but only cache it, not add it as a dependency.