# Not Able to Install Angular CLI due to Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: angular, npm, installation, cmd, using

while installing angular/cli using npm I am getting below error. I even tried reinstalling node.js and tried to install angular cli through below commands

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

also tried

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
```

but still same error is popping up.

```
C:\Users\USER>npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"babel-polyfill":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-14T19_32_16_080Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my problem is finally solved - installation of angular/cli successful.

Run the following command in cmd promt :

1. npm cache verify
   --> run the command in cmd which verify your NPM cached memory.
2. npm cache clear --force
   --> it will be cleaning your NPM cache memory.
3. npm install –g @angular/cli@latest
   --> now tried installing with this command
4. ng --version
   --> to check the installed version of angular.

Thanks to all guys..

Answer (score 0):

Check if your package.json is a valid JSON. Quite probable that you have an extra or a missing comma.

Comment: Thank for your reply Aram, how do I get to know that its a valid JSON. Actually I am new to angular, just starting.. please clarify..I'll try..

Comment: Try online tools for validating JSON (in case your IDE is not capable of doing it), e.g. https://jsonformatter.org. Put all your JSON files there and ensure they all are valid.

Comment: ok Aram I'll try.. thanks and I got the solution for my question which I posted, please check it once. thanks for your valuable reply..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a corrupt file in your cached node modules file.

Try below;

Run `npm install -g @angular/cli --force`. This should force a new installation of the package

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I tried, but this command also not working, still the same error I am getting..