# failed to install with npm, invalid json response

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I had already install npm before, but somehow I had to uninstall it for some reason.
Now, i tried to install npm again to create react app with this command.

> `npx create-react-app ip_tracker`

On a halfway installation I found this error

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fpreset-react reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ngebelcilik/.npm/_logs/2020-11-27T14_34_28_241Z-debug.log
```

Here's the logs

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'create-react-app',
0 verbose cli   'ip_tracker'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.0.11
2 info using node@v12.19.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 7ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 10ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 10ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 8ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/ngebelcilik/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 2ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 4ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 44ms
18 verbose npm-session 9047ea92ff92abbf
19 timing npm:load Completed in 86ms
20 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app 835ms
21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 4ms
22 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
23 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
24 timing command:exec Completed in 416430ms
25 verbose stack Error: command failed
25 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
25 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
25 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
25 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
26 verbose cwd /home/ngebelcilik
27 verbose Linux 5.4.0-51-generic
28 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "create-react-app" "ip_tracker"
29 verbose node v12.19.0
30 verbose npm  v7.0.11
31 error code 1
32 error path /home/ngebelcilik
33 error command failed
34 error command sh -c create-react-app ip_tracker
35 verbose exit 1
```

I already doing research on this error, it's similiar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625539/npm-err-invalid-json-response-body-at-http-registry-npmjs-org-ansi-escapes-re) problem, but this problem happened everytime I install any npm packages (not just react).

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: It might be a local caching issue. Can you please run `npm cache clean --force` and then try again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Viral Patel comment solved it for me. Problem was solved by cleaning the local cache with.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: it didnt work for me

Comment: ~ $ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just ran the `npm install` again, it took a long time but it worked. It could have been a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fpreset-react reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

This means you are getting bad JSON in the response. There could be a number of reasons you get that error ranging from a network issue on your end to an issue with the npm servers. fwiw that resource does return valid json for me...

Try to curl the resource and see if the response is JSON:

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fpreset-react | python -m json.tool
```