# Installing expo-cli with npm gives me error

Tags: npm, expo

I have a very stable internet connection but anytime i run the command `npm install -g expo-cli` i get the errors below.

I have no clue as to how to go about it, i guessed it was a network connection issue so i tried everything but still it isn't working

```
freduah@freduah:~$ npm install -g expo-cli
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T14_27_48_963Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~$
```

After adding `--loglevel verbose` command the logs i received are below

```
freduah@freduah:~/ExpoTest$ npm install -g expo-cli --loglevel verbose
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'expo-cli',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@7.5.2
npm info using node@v12.21.0
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/freduah/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 11ms
npm verb npm-session fbfdf28f750a4e2b
npm timing npm:load Completed in 28ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 11ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 2ms
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli 2711ms (from cache)
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 2729ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/expo-cli Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 2731ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 2749ms
npm timing command:install Completed in 2775ms
npm verb type invalid-json
npm verb stack FetchError: invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
npm verb stack     at /usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/body.js:77:31
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:874:19)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:824:11)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:209:7)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:127:5)
npm verb stack     at async install (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/install.js:38:3)
npm verb cwd /home/freduah/ExpoTest
npm verb Linux 5.5.0-kali2-amd64
npm verb argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "expo-cli" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb node v12.21.0
npm verb npm  v7.5.2
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 3130ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T14_45_02_470Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~/ExpoTest$
```

After applying the solution provided by [Aydin K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470517/aydin-k)
The download procedures successfully continued but then,
I encountered   new problems, i was able to work around some and now i'm stuck at the error below

I got the error after running the command `npm install -g expo-cli --loglevel verbose --legacy-peer-deps`

```
pm verb type invalid-json
npm verb stack FetchError: invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
npm verb stack     at /usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/body.js:77:31
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm verb stack     at async Promise.all (index 46)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:854:5)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:209:7)
npm verb stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:127:5)
npm verb stack     at async install (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/install.js:38:3)
npm verb cwd /home/freduah/ExpoTest
npm verb Linux 5.5.0-kali2-amd64
npm verb argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "expo-cli" "--loglevel" "verbose" "--force" "--legacy-peer-deps"
npm verb node v12.21.0
npm verb npm  v7.5.2
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 194205ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T17_18_03_855Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~/ExpoTest$
```

Comment: Try increasing log level like described here to find out how the actual non-json response looks like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412424/how-to-see-logs-from-npm-installation

Comment: question updated with the logs

Comment: Here are some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039535/failed-to-install-with-npm-invalid-json-response

Comment: You’re welcome  :-)

Comment: Hey Man. I've updated my question with the new error i'm facing.
Would you mind taking a look ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237491/discussion-between-freduah-gideon-and-aydin-k).