# nx workspace angular monorepo throws error while creating new app

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx, nx.dev, angular-workspace-configuration

I am creating new angular monorepo application, I run following command:

```
npx create-nx-workspace explorer --preset=angular
```

but I am getting following error once it executes:

```
√ Installing dependencies with npm
× Creating your workspace in explorer

 >  NX   Nx failed to create a workspace.

   Exit code: 1
   Log file: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-21320-9eV8hcpfQJm2\error.log
```

File logs are as follows:

```
2590 error invalid json response body at typescript-estree reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
2591 verbose exit 1
```

Is it because I am behind company's VPN or do I need to do something to handle it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely because of company firewall. Have you tried without?

Comment: I just tried but still same error.

Comment: Maybe this? https://letscodepare.com/blog/npm-err-invalid-json-response-body-unexpected-end-of-json-input

Comment: There's also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625539/npm-err-invalid-json-response-body-at-http-registry-npmjs-org-ansi-escapes-re

Comment: Did you tried to start simple npx create-nx-workspace and set up the configs during the setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fix it using following commands:

```
 npm cache clean --force

npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

npm cache verify
```

And once it is able to run then again I added my org's proxy config again.

Also,
Comment the .npmrc file as well