# NPM error while trying to make a auth system using Laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel, authentication, npm, breeze

When I run `npm install`, I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Install Error:Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nt-webpack-plugin":"0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675478/npm-install-errorunexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-nt-webpack)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Update your node.js to the latest
- make sure that the node version is up to date by running:

  $ node -v

in your CMD and by visiting
https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
To know what is the latest version.

- run this command in your CMD:

  $ npm cache clean --force
- then Delete node_modules by running:

  $ rmdir /S /Q node_modules

or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash. If you are not updating your packages you can delete the package-lock.json file too.

- now you can run:

  $ npm install

This works for me, all the best.

Comment: I runned npm cache clean --force and runned NPM install as root, and it worked for me. Thank you very much